# The use of "habit " as an alternative to "used to"

Tags: grammar

Are the following structures synonyms?
I used to smoke.
I was in the habit of smoking.
I got into the habit of smoking.
I fell into the habit of smoking.

Comment: No.  Look up "habit" in a dictionary.

Comment: None of the dictionaries is discussing such a difference.

Comment: I'm wondering if this would not have been a better question for [ell.se]. To the O.P.: you can [read this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell/3723#3723), and use that to figure out where you might want to ask future questions.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. *I **was** in the habit of smoking.*
> 2. *I **got** in(to) the habit of smoking.*
> 3. *I **fell** into the habit of smoking.*
> 4. *I **used to** smoke.*

(1-4) are all grammatical, and can all be used to describe the same contexts,
but they don't have the same grammar, and they don't mean the same things.

- (4) is an idiomatic past auxiliary construction [*used to*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83557/15299) (pronounced /'yustu/ or /'yustə/),
  which takes an infinitive complement (here the habitual generic infinitive *to smoke*).

The others are stative and inchoative uses of the idiom *`Det` habit of `V`-ing*,
using a container metaphor, whence *in* or *into*:

- (1) is a normal stative Locative construction, auxiliary *be* + `PreoPh`; *into* is **not allowed** here.
- (2) is an inchoative construction (*get* is an inchoative for *be*), using the same metaphor.
  It comments on the initiation of the habit; if it's considered as motion, *into* is **allowed** here.
- (3) is a more metaphoric inchoative, adding a gravitational field to the container,
  and requiring a motion construal of the initiation as a *fall*; *into* is **required** here.

As for meanings,

- (4) states that I smoked at a past time and presupposes that I no longer do.
- (1) states that I smoked at a past time and invites the inference that I no longer do.
- (2) states that I started to smoke and continued the habit of smoking at a past time.
  It says nothing about the present state of my habits; this must be determined from context.
- (3) makes the same statement as (2), but construes the initiation of the habit as an error.

As you can see, there are no synonyms here;
indeed, once you look at the fine structure of anything, there are no real synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

No. All of these constructs could refer to the same thing, but they don't convey the exact same meaning.

"I used to smoke" - perhaps the speaker only smoked occasionally, not habitually, and has since stopped. This sentence doesn't describe a habit, even though it could be referring to one: "I used to smoke two packs a day" would clearly indicate habitual smoking.

"Used to" also works for things we wouldn't describe as habitual: "I used to have a blue car" wouldn't be well replaced with "I was in the habit of having a blue car," for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, the speaker is merely stating a fact. In the other sentences, he focuses on a particular pattern of behaviour : http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+into+the+habit+of

Comment: I really appreciate all of your answers.Thank you so much.