# Using "used to" with past tense

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Why are we not allowed to use the "used to" in the following sentences?

> - I used to work hard last month.
> - I used to live in London three years ago.

And could you please recommend a grammar book for advanced learners.

Comment: Have you seen our [ell.se] site?

Comment: I see no problem with _I used to live in London three years ago_. _I used to work hard last month_ is odd only because _used to_ implies longer ago than last month.

Comment: The first one is wrong because _work hard_ refers to a long-term habit, and [_used to_ presupposes that it has changed](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83557/15299). _I used to work hard_ is perfectly grammatical. But adding _last month_ limits the duration of the habit to one month, including the change. This is a contradiction. You could say _I used to work hard, but I stopped last month_, which puts the events in temporal perspective. As Colin points out, _I used to live in London 3 years ago_ is OK, though _I lived in London 3 years ago_ is just as good and has no meaning difference.

Comment: @ColinFine I expect it's after "I used to live in London" **or** "I lived in London 3 years ago"

Comment: @marcellothearcane: You expect that _what_ is after those? I've said that I see no problem with _I used to live in London three years ago_. To put it another way, _I used to live in London three years ago_ seems fine to me.

Comment: @ColinFine looks like homework to me, so the teacher/textbook.