# I used to work at McDonalds or I worked at McDonalds

Tags: used-to

Question to Americans (I'm interested in US version of English):

Imagine your first job was at McDonalds.
You’re telling about it to a friend.
Would you rather say:

1a) I worked at McDonalds as a teenager.

1b) I used to work at McDonalds as a teenager.

1c) both

Imagine you took piano lessons when you were a teenager and were good at it. But you no longer doing it.

2a) I played piano as a teenager.

2b) I used to play piano as a teenager.

2c) both

thank you so much!
Sergey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'used to' describing something changed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/is-used-to-describing-something-changed)

Comment: @livresque not really. I'd better update the question.

Comment: Are you aware that "Do you play piano?" ***really*** means "Do you KNOW HOW TO play THE piano?"